# Explicit formula for a series

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits

It is well known that, if $c_1 > 0$, then
$$
\sum\limits_{n=\ell }^{\infty} \exp\{ - c_1  \, n\} = \frac{ \exp\{ -c_1 \ell \} }{1 - \exp\{  - c_1  \} }.
$$
Is there an explicit formula for the next expression
$$
\sum\limits_{n=\ell  }^{\infty} \exp\{ - c_1  \, n+ c_2 \sqrt{n} \}, 
$$
where $c_2 > 0$?

Comment: If it exists, Mathematica is not aware of it.

Comment: I'd say this is highly unlikely.